# lookup data in a datatable and add it to a new column

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables as shown below:
**bigrams**

```
 w1w2           freq   w1          w2      
 common names   1      common      names  
 department of  4      department  of  
 family name    6      family      name  

bigrams = setDT(structure(list(w1w2 = c("common names", "department of", "family name"
), freq = c(1L, 4L, 6L), w1 = c("common", "department", "family"
), w2 = c("names", "of", "name")), .Names = c("w1w2", "freq", 
"w1", "w2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"))
```

**unigrams**

```
w1            freq  
common        2  
department    3  
family        4  
name          5  
names         1  
of            9  

unigrams = setDT(structure(list(w1 = c("common", "department", "family", "name", 
"names", "of"), freq = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 9L)), .Names = c("w1", 
"freq"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

**desired output**

```
 w1w2           freq   w1          w2      w1freq    w2freq  
 common names   1      common      names   2         1
 department of  4      department  of      3         9
 family name    6      family      name    4         5
```

**What I have done so far**

```
setkey(bigrams, w1)
setkey(unigrams, w1)
result <- bigrams[unigrams]
```

This gives me the `i.freq` column for `w1` but when I try to do the same for `w2` the `i.freq` column is updated to reflect the freq of `w2`.

**How can I get freq for both `w1` and `w2` in separate columns?**

Note: I have already seen solutions to [data.table Lookup value and translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22396652/data-table-lookup-value-and-translate) and [Modify column of a data.table based on another column and add the new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788113/modify-column-of-a-data-table-based-on-another-column-and-add-the-new-column)

Comment: Are you looking for a data.table solution? Otherwise this should work: bigrams$w1freq <- unigrams$freq[match(bigrams$w1, unigrams$w1)]; bigrams$w2freq <- unigrams$freq[match(bigrams$w2, unigrams$w1)];

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes I would prefer to solve it using data.table, as i plan to use the solution for larger data set.

Comment: is your `freq` column in your desired output correct?

Comment: @Symbolix No it wasn't but I have corrected, thanks

Comment: thought so - now my solution makes sense :)

Comment: Next time, please consider making your example more easily reproduced. This is a pain to read in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do two joins, and in v1.9.6 of `data.table` you can specify the `on=` argument for differing column names.

```
library(data.table)

bigrams[unigrams, on=c("w1"), nomatch = 0][unigrams, on=c(w2 = "w1"), nomatch = 0]

            w1w2 freq         w1    w2 i.freq i.freq.1
1:   family name    6     family  name      4        5
2:  common names    1     common names      2        1
3: department of    4 department    of      3        9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a bit of reshaping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bigrams %>%
  rename(w1w2_string = w1w2,
         w1w2_freq = freq) %>%
  gather(order, string,
         w1, w2) %>%
  left_join(unigrams %>%
              rename(string = w1) ) %>%
  gather(type, value,
         string, freq) %>%
  unite(order_type, order, type) %>%
  spread(order_type, value)
```

Edit: Explanation

The first observation you can make is that bigrams contains in fact information about three different units of analysis: a bigram and two unigrams. Convert to long form so that the unit of analysis is a unigram.  Then we can merge in the other unigram data. Now note that your unigram has two different pieces of information per row: the frequency for the unigram, and the text of the unigram. Convert to long form again so that the unit of analysis is a piece of information about a unigram. Now spread, so that each new column is a type of information about a unigram.

Comment: could you please explain the solution a bit?